# Syntax error in php.ini

Tags: php

I'm no web guy myself, but I had to do some changes on our webserver (CentOS 6, Plesk11, PHP 5.4.24, Zend Engine 2.4.0) and add a cron job. The cron job runs beautifully, but I am getting continuous emails  with an error in the php.ini file:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /etc/php.ini on line 1
```

php.ini:

```
a:4:{s:4:"hash";i:1311888988;s:5:"mtime";i:1420189174;s:6:"expire";i:1420196374;s:4:"tags";a:1:{i:0;s:15:"da1_Zend_Locale";}}
```

I tried looking up the php.ini syntax, but what's in there has nothing to do with what I found. I presume it's related to the Plesk control panel somehow, but I didn't want to do any stupid changes until I understood what everything does.

Thanks in advance, I presume it's quite a simple fix.

Alex

Comment: That is an array that has been serialized by PHP and is invalid in a php.ini file.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like your php.ini was overwritten by something... I'm frankly surprised PHP works at all.

Comment: Might want to re-install php. Your version is way out of date anyway...